# How-To: Get meta data from the users last order in woocommerce

Tags: users, woocommerce-offtopic, api

How do I retrieve the last order of a current logged in user on my site and take a value from their last order?

I am trying to take a value from a field in the database 'Time' from the customers order and store that in a variable to use elsewhere.

I've tried a few things:

- //var_dump($appointment->get_order()->get_order_number());
- //$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
- //var_dump($order);

However my PHP skill is not very great and I've been stuck on this problem for 3 days. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to grab the last order ID, you can do it with a simple WP_Query

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'product',
                 'posts_per_page'=>1,
                 'orderby'=>'ID',
                 'orderby'=>'DESC');
$query= WP_Query($args);
```

As this will only give only one result, you don't need to loop the result,

```
$order_id= $query->posts[0]->ID;
```

Now, you can reach the order data,

```
$order = WC_Order($order_id);
```

You can use the object with any woocommerce order related functions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the response!

I've tried to run this code in my functions.php file however nothing is happening after:

$query = WP_Query($args);

when I try to var_dump this onto my-account page nothing is returned. Could this be to do with the values in the array?

Comment: Yes, you need to add 'numberposts' => $order_count,
 'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
 'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
 'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
 'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses()

Comment: This part comes from the file woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php